# Firebird: Permission Denied?

Tags: database, cmd, command-prompt, firebird

I opened Firebird ISQL Tool to create a database (I assume thats right?) and I typed in the "create database 'path_here'" command to create my database. When I pressed enter, it asked me for a CON string, so I typed in the below:

```
ISQL Version: WI-V3.0.1.32609 Firebird 3.0
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> create database 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Remake\FirebirdDatabase'
CON> user 'SYSDBA' password 'myPASSWORD123';
```

When clicking enter, I received this error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "CreateFile (create)" operation for file "C:\USERS\USER\DESKTOP\REMAKE\FIREBIRDDATABASE"
-Error while trying to create file
-Access is denied.
SQL>
```

Is there a way to fix this? I googled it and all the answers pretty much give information for Linux and nothing for windows.

Comment: Are you logged in with the user `User`?, what are the permissions on the folder `Remake` on your desktop?

Comment: I've checked all that, the user I am logged in with has every single permission.

Comment: That is not what I asked, you are creating a database in `C:\Users\User`, are you logged in as that user? Otherwise you don't have write access to that location. Also, how did you start isql, which commandline options did you use? Note that you usually access a Firebird database through a Firebird service, so creating a database in a user folder might not be the best strategy if you want it accessible to the server process running under a different user.

Comment: I'm logged in to the User account, I would of said if I wasn't. And I opened the ISQL from the 'Recently Added' programs in the start menu. I have also tried running it as Administrator.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164602/firebird-access-denied

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can reproduce this error, is if `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Remake\FirebirdDatabase` already exists, and `FirebirdDatabase` is a folder (directory), and not a file.

The database path you give in [`create database`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-db.html#fblangref25-ddl-db-create) is the full path to a database file. So make sure there is no folder `FirebirdDatabase` in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Remake`. It is customary to give Firebird databases the file extension `.fdb`.

Answer (score -1):

With your version of Firebird, there is no need to quote the name of the user name, which is also case insensitive.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Also, Firebird user names can be case sensitive since Firebird 3, following the same rules as for identifiers (so using double quotes). The single quotes around the username are still possible for backwards compatibility.